# How to access Sound Manager2 created sound object?

Tags: javascript, html, object, audio

In soundmanger2 http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

I created the following sound object:

```
soundManager.setup({
  url: '<?php echo $html->url('/') ?>js/swf/',
  flashVersion: 9, // optional: shiny features (default = 8)
  useFlashBlock: false, // optionally, enable when you're ready to dive in
  allowScriptAccess: 'always',
  /**
   * read up on HTML5 audio support, if you're feeling adventurous.
   * iPad/iPhone and devices without flash installed will always attempt to use it.
   */
  onready: function() {
    //defaultReader = 'Menshawi_16kbps';
    soundManager.createSound({
  id: defaultReader,
  url: '<?php echo $html->url('/').'assets/audio/\'+defaultReader+\''.$mp3; ?>',
  autoLoad: false,
  autoPlay: true,
  onload: function() {
    //alert('The sound '+this.id+' loaded!');
  },
  onplay: function(){
    $('#'+defaultReader).removeClass('sm2_link');
    $('#'+defaultReader).addClass('sm2_playing');
    $.cookie('defaultReader', defaultReader, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    $('#'+defaultReader).click(function(){
      //alert('ho')

      soundManager.togglePause(defaultReader);
      return false;


    });

  },

  onfinish: function(){
    $('#'+defaultReader).addClass('sm2_link');
    $('#'+defaultReader).removeClass('sm2_playing');

  },
  volume: 100
});
  }
});
```

I want to access the object created by soundManager.createSound from another script tag
for example:

```
<script>
theSoundObjectCreated.play()
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup your soundmanager with something like this

`window.soundManager = new SoundManager();`

Then use `soundManager.setup(.....)`

You would load/create a sound with

```
soundManager.createSound({
    id: 'some-id-for-your-sound',
    url: "url-to-your-sound.mp3",
    autoLoad: true,
    autoPlay: false,
    volume: 40
});
```

And you can play that sound with

`soundManager.getSoundById("some-id-for-your-sound").play()`